# Custom usage message for a single argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a parameter that can be specified by the user with either one or two arguments:

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--start", required=True, metavar='START_TIME', 
  nargs='+', help="The start time either in milliseconds or as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS.")
```

The help message shows this:

```
usage: foo
   -s START_TIME [START_TIME ...]

Foo

optional arguments:
  -s START_TIME [START_TIME ...], --start START_TIME [START_TIME ...]
                    The start time of the query window either in
                    milliseconds or as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hr).
```

This is somewhat misleading because of the `[START_TIME ...]` part. Is there a way that I can modify the usage message for this one argument so that it shows something more like:

```
usage: foo
   -s START_TIME

Foo

optional arguments:
  -s START_TIME, --start START_TIME
                    The start time of the query window either in
                    milliseconds or as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hr).
```

I know I can replace the entire usage message with argparse, but I have several other arguments that I don't want to mess with. I would like do do something like `nargs='1|2', but I'm afraid that might be wishful thinking... Other than restructuring my CLI, is there something I can do to fix the usage message for a single parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest removing `nargs` from your call to `add_argument`. `nargs='+'` indicates there may be more than one input for that argument, but in actuality you always want one argument. A string of `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` is one argument conceptually and may be passed in with quotes:

```
python script.py -s 978370496000
python script.py -s "01/01/2001 12:34:56"

python temp3.py -h
usage: temp3.py [-h] -s START_TIME

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s START_TIME, --start START_TIME
                        The start time either in milliseconds or as MM/DD/YYYY
                        HH:MM:SS.
```

This will produce your desired usage message, and I think will be less confusing to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Karin. I was trying to make my program more flexible so that users didn't have to wrap their time argument in quotes, but I guess I might just be making it more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The default display for a `'+'` nargs is this `S [S ...]`.  It's supposed to convey the idea that you have to give at least one value, but can have more.  (look at what `*` produces).

```
In [306]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [307]: a1=parser.add_argument('-s',nargs='+')
In [308]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-s S [S ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -s S [S ...]
```

In your case the `metavar` string is just replacing that default string derived from the `dest`.

You can give a tuple metavar, which displays as:

```
In [309]: a1.metavar=('A','B')
In [310]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-s A [B ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -s A [B ...]
```

empty metavar:

```
In [312]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-s  [...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -s  [ ...]
```

To override this formatting

```
'%s [%s ...]' % get_metavar(2)
```

you'd have to create a custom `HelpFormatter` subclass with a modified `_format_args` method.

=================

As for  `nargs='1|2'` I've explored adding a range option modeled on `regex` syntax.  It's not hard to add, but you have to be familiar with the `argparse.py` code.  There's a Python bug/issue on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! However, I think I am going to go with a more simple approach.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to have zero, one or two arguments and not more, you can have two options `-s1` and `-s2`.

It can be more obvious or clearer for the user to understand the usage of your application.